# Mongoose query find specifi element in array of object

Tags: mongoose

i have a dbSchema like that

```
blockNumber: { type: Number },
transactions: [
{
blockHash: { type: String },
from: { type: String },
gas: { type: String },
gasPrice: { type: String },
hash: { type: String },
nonce: { type: String },
to: { type: String },
value: { type: String },
status: { type: String },
blockNumber: { type: Number },
tx_Fee: { type: String },
TimeStamp: {type: String},
}
]
```

1 How i find the single object which  hash = 'some Value'
2 How i find all the transactions object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 You need to use the dot notation for subdocumnent queries.

```
Model.findOne({"transactions.hash": YOUR_HASH })
```

2 You need $unwind and $replaceRoot aggregations.

```
Model.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$transactions"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$transactions" }
    }
]);
```

Comment: If you need to find a spicific transaction from the aggregation, simply add an $match pipeline to the end of aggregate() argument array:  
  {  $match : { hash: YOUR_HASH}  }

Comment: Model.findOne({"transactions.hash": YOUR_HASH }).This query is not working it give me the whole transactions object which contain all the object i need single object wtih hash=myHash.

Comment: Does the second code with { $match : { hash: YOUR_HASH} } addition fit your needs?

Comment: i write the query  like this
 Model.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$transactions"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$transactions" }
    }, { $match : { hash: YOUR_HASH} }                                                                                                                   
]);
but it is not working

Comment: It should work. What do you receive? All transactions, empty array or error?

Comment: it is working now thanks.kindly can you suggest me some good resource to learn mongoose query?

Comment: If you're not familliar with mongodb aggragate, you can just use find() and work with the result as with an javascript array. It will be a bit slower, but not critical. If you want to examine the aggregation queries, simply read mongodb documentation.